# Spring + DWR fie upload size restriction

Tags: spring, file-upload, size, multipart, dwr

I have an application in which files can be uploaded into the application using `MultiPartRequest` or DWR.

I have the following configuration.

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>nerp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fileUploadMaxBytes</param-name>
        <param-value>5000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>nerp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/nerp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>nerp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**nerp-servlet.xml**

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="com.resources.erp.util.ERPMultiPartResolver">
   <!--  one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes  -->
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</beans:bean>
```

**ERPMultiPartResolver**

```
public class ERPMultiPartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {
@Override
public boolean isMultipart(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean isMultiPartBoolean = true;
    final String urlFromBrowserWithAppName = String.valueOf(request.getRequestURI());
    String urlFromBrowser = "";

    if(urlFromBrowserWithAppName != null) {
        urlFromBrowser = urlFromBrowserWithAppName.replaceAll(String.valueOf(request.getContextPath()),"");
    }
    if(urlFromBrowser.indexOf("dwr") > 0) {
        isMultiPartBoolean = false;
    }
    else {
        isMultiPartBoolean = super.isMultipart(request);
    }
    return isMultiPartBoolean;
}
```

}

My `MultiPartRequest` related upload is getting restricted to the size specified in `maxUploadSize` property of the `ERPMultiPartResolver`. But I am not able to restrict the size of the DWR file upload.

I tried using the param-name `fileUploadMaxBytes` in web.xml but the image size is not getting restricted.

Can someone please help me out on how to restrict the size of the Image through DWR upload when both Spring 3.2.1 and Dwr 3.0 are being used in the project?

I have checked the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my above question is that instead of declaring the **fileUploadMaxBytes** in web.xml in the manner I did above, the declaration should be in the place where you configure your dwrContoller. i.e.

```
 <dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" >
    <dwr:config-param name="fileUploadMaxBytes" value="1048"/>
 </dwr:controller>
```

Now with the help of this, I am able to restrict the image size to 1048 bytes.

Earlier my dwrController configuration is as shown below

```
<dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" />
```